# how do i create a downloadable gallery with image descriptions?

Tags: gallery

I am creating an educational site for medical students using wordpress and would like to have an image gallery that displays a short description of each image and has a selection box beside it (as well as the option to select all/ none) then once the required images have been selected the visitor can just hit a download button to download all the selected images into a zip file.

I am aware that there is an extension to the nextGen gallery: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-download-gallery/

that will allow downloads but it does not display the gallery well if the image name is longer than one word as it flows over the following image and hides it while distorting the gallery layout.

I wondered if there was a single plugin that will do this without the overflow bug as I sadly lack the coding skills to create one myself.

..by image description i mean something along the lies of "patient displaying x symptoms of y disease at n stage"

Comment: Note that you can easily create your own template to use with that plugin. Just follow [these instructions](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/creating-a-custom-gallery-template-for-nextgen-gallery/) for creating a custom gallery template, but copy the gallery template from the download gallery plugin and adapt that to suit.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug, it's a style matter *(that maybe renders the Question off-topic)*.

Using the Nextgen Download Gallery plugin, this can be solved by simply applying the following rule to your theme's `style.css` file:

```
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail {
    width: 120px;
}
```

*Adjusting the width to match your theme's design.*

And even the following rule, if there are incredibly large words, like [Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis)...

```
.ngg-gallery-thumbnail label span {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[image]